# Redirection from a page in teams app blocking my page

Tags: javascript, microsoft-teams

I have created a Microsoft teams app that contains a chatbot and few tabs. In one of the tabs, I am redirecting to our OAuth page for getting access token. When i make the redirection from my app I am getting error as

**Refused to display 'my_url' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.** Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Teams tab is implemented on I-frame. And Authentication dialog is usually restricted to open in I-Frames. That's why you are getting this error. Instead you can open the Auth URL inside a popup, and after successful login redirect user to your tab.

Please have a look into [Microsoft Teams authentication flow for tabs flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-flow-tab)

Here is a ink for [Auth code sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-complete-node/tree/master/src/views/tab-auth)